# Usando & em pesquisa Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Estou com uma dúvida sobre a utilização de & no Oracle.

Vejam abaixo a minha tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao consultar pela descrição 'Easy Breezy Emailmkt & Eu', o Oracle abre um janela para passagem de parâmetro, conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha pergunta, tenho como consultar com o &, sem que o banco entenda isso como uma variável? e sem usar um set define off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalmente para resolver quando utilizo PLSQL, faço da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MARK_CAMPANHA
-- WHERE DESCRICAO = 'Easy Breezy Emailmkt '||'&'||' Eu';
```

Pesquisando um pouco agora, achei utilizando `SET ESCAPE`, utilizando SQLDeveloper.

```
SET ESCAPE ON
SET ESCAPE "\"
SELECT * 
  FROM MARK_CAMPANHA
-- WHERE DESCRICAO = 'Easy Breezy Emailmkt \& Eu';
```

E uma terceira opção, parecida com a primeira seria:

```
 SELECT * 
      FROM MARK_CAMPANHA
    -- WHERE DESCRICAO = 'Easy Breezy Emailmkt'||chr(38)||' Eu';
```

Comment: Obrigado mesmo @David. Todas funcionaram, mas fiquei com a primeira. Abraço

Answer (score 1):

Cara a melhor opção seria desligar o Define oracle que tem essa função de chamar variavel. Em seguida voce executa a query.

***SET DEFINE OFF;***

depois vc pode ligar:
SET DEFINE ON;

obs: Esse set só ocorre na sua sessão de usuario, por padrão o define oracle é sempre ON.

Abraços